# Changing the integer in the String in Java

Tags: java, string

I need to change the string by decreasing the number by one e.g. 011 then 010 etc. if 009 then 008.

However, I cannot think of the ways to do this thing please help me:

```
<img width="188" height="307" src="File1.files/image006.png" alt="NNMF_Input.png" v:shapes="image_x0020_33" />
<img width="506" height="200" src="File1.files/image014.png" v:shapes="image_x0020_1" />
<img width="506" height="411" src="File1.files/image016.png" v:shapes="image_x0020_2" />
<img width="515" height="179" src="File1.files/image018.png" v:shapes="image_x0020_3" />
```

Here, I want to change `files/image006.png` to `files/image005.png` and change say
`files/image010.png` to `files/image009.png`.

P.S. They are all in strings! not HTML tags in fact

Comment: One Way is: a). Convert String to Integer, b). Decrement Integer, c). Convert back to String.

Comment: Yeah but the thing is that I can do that but the problem is I have to extract the part of the string and then put it back to where it was.. and it is 000 thing so it is not just 18 17 thing.

Comment: And use DecimalFormat to get the result formatted just the way you want it.

Comment: That is unsatisfactory since I want to automate this (not just them but say 100 of them)

Comment: Particia, that function won't do the job here... it is not about formatting decimals...

Comment: Use regex to get the `Integer` and `Name` part of your String separately and then concat after making you change.

Comment: Do you really want to do that in Java or did you mean Javascript? Asking because of HTML code.

Comment: Rekesh, that sounds good though I haven't used regex I will search for it.

Comment: Ocaso Protal, yes in Java they are strings.

Comment: why dont you manage numeric values in integers and then concatenate them with string? I think that will be easy to manipulate integers and strings as well. You can easily decrement these numbers.

Comment: Can you show us your Java code? Is this HTML inside a stringbuiler? Or inside a View? Or a normal string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try regex

```
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?<=/image)\\d{3}").matcher(str);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while(m.find()) {
        m.appendReplacement(sb, String.format("%03d", Integer.parseInt(m.group()) - 1));
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
```

Comment: Hi, I am pretty new to regex. Could you please tell me how I would get just the File1.files/image006.png from an img tag using Regex?

Comment: @user3278450 You can find the basic Regex tutorial here : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Comment: mmm.. I do not know how to add more rules with the current regex in compile for example, ^"src=" .png"$ (but I want to exclude them ..please help me!)

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = Integer.parseInt("011");
System.out.format("%03d", i-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for funny - scala solution :)

```
scala> def increment(str:String) = str.split("[^0-9]").
filter( s => s.nonEmpty && s.length >1).
foldLeft(str)((acc,curr) => acc.replace(curr, {val res = (curr.toInt+1).toString;Range(0,curr.length - res.length).
foldLeft(res)((acc,curr)=> "0"+acc) }))
increment: (str: String)String

scala> increment("File1.files/image014.png")
res10: String = File1.files/image015.png
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "000110";

// Get the last index and add 1 to determine number of leading zeros
int i = str.lastIndexOf('0') + 1;

// Subtract or do any math on the number you want
int newNumber = Integer.parseInt(str) - 1;

// Format the new string with leading zeros
String newString = String.format("%0" + i + "d", newNumber);

// See the new string
System.out.println(newString);
```

**EDIT**

To answer your edited question:

```
String str = "image0110";

// Get the number (above example 0110) from original string using the last character 'e 'from 'image'
str = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('e') + 1);

// Get how many leading zeros are in there
int i = str.lastIndexOf('0') + 1;

// Do the math
int newNumber = Integer.parseInt(str) - 1;

// Form the new string starting with 'image' and leading zeros
String newString = "image" + String.format("%0" + i + "d", newNumber);

System.out.println(newString);
```